# Truncation issue with 19 digit long integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, decimal, truncation

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sgE5.png)

I downloaded a CSV file from a web service. When I import the csv using `pandas.read_csv`, the 19 digit long IDs are truncated to decimals. I then use `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.6f}'.format` to display the IDs in full. However, when I compare the ID with the one in web service, python changed the last 3 digits entirely, keeping only the first 16 digits. I thought it was the csv file problem when I downloaded it but when I use Notepad to open it, the IDs are the same as in the web service. I have tried something like

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, dtype={'ID':str})
```

and

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, dtype={'ID':np.int})
```

but the codes do not work.

I have attached a screenshot of the DataFrame for better illustration of my problem. Is there any way to keep the IDs unchange? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me default solution working, but maybe need `np.int64`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, dtype={'ID':np.int64})
```

If possible some missing values and pandas version is 0.24+ use [`Int64`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, dtype={'ID':'Int64'})
```

Comment: I get ValueError: cannot safely convert passed user dtype of int64 for float64 dtyped data. I think it's because some cells has NaN values.

Comment: I still get the same ValueError.

Comment: @ShaunLim - Is your pandas version `0.24+` ? If yes, what code return `ValueError` ?

Comment: - I'm using Jupyter notebook. The error now is "ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 11" (which is the ID column). I tried import the large file by chunk, and import the first N row without NaN value, the IDs match the Web Service's IDs. Then, I tried to download the first 100,00 rows of the exact same data from the web service and coded `df.fillna( { 'ID':0 } )`, and imported it to Jupyter notebook, and it worked! But the thing is I downloaded the data from Databricks in bulk, so `df.fillna( { 'ID':0 } )` does not work because the code for bulk download is different

Comment: ... or maybe there's a way to put in `df.fillna( { 'ID':0 } )` in the bulk download codes which I do not know. But anyway, at least now I know it's the NA values that are leading to this problem. Do you have any idea on how to fix it? Is there a way to import files and drop NA at the same time? I found that when I imported the file, the IDs are OK if the chunk does not contain NaN values in the ID column. The moment the ID column contains NaN values, all the ID values will be changed to a different number (the last 3-4 digits).